# Updating and Deleting Payment Methods with Acumatica API

Tags: acumatica

Thanks to the post on [Creating customer payment method with api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683250/acumatica-creating-customer-payment-method-with-api) I am able to create a new Payment Method successfully using the API.  But I can't figure out how to update or delete an existing payment method.  There doesn't seem to be any type of key field.  I've updated and deleted Contacts and Locations with the API, but Contacts have Contact IDs, and Locations have LocationIDs.  There doesn't seem to be a PaymentMethodID.  I thought maybe the "Card/Account No." field might function as that, but I wasn't able to make that work.  And I've noticed that I can save two Payment Methods with identical card numbers, so that would make identical keys if that field was used anyway.

Here's the code I tried for updating.  It's mostly Chris's code from the other post I linked to, but trying to add an extra key field for the update.

```
Public Function UpdateCreditCard(ByVal customerID As String, ByVal existingAcctNum As String, ByVal paymentMethodCode As String, ByVal CCNum As String, ByVal expiration As String, ByVal nameOnCard As String, ByVal active As Boolean)
    Dim paymentMethod As AR303010Content = m_context.AR303010GetSchema()
    m_context.AR303010Clear()

    ' main level fields
    Dim customerVal As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer, customerID)
    Dim paymentMethodCodeVal As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodSelection.PaymentMethod, paymentMethodCode)

    ' inner level fields
    Dim ccNumName As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Description, "CCDNUM")
    Dim ccNumValue As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, CCNum, True)

    Dim ccExpName As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Description, "EXPDATE")
    Dim ccExpValue As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, expiration, True)

    Dim ccNameName As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Description, "NAMEONCC")
    Dim ccNameValue As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, nameOnCard, True)

    Dim saveCommands() As Command
    If existingAcctNum = "" Then
        ' new credit card
        saveCommands = {customerVal, paymentMethod.Actions.Insert, paymentMethodCodeVal, ccNumName, ccNumValue, ccExpName, ccExpValue, ccNameName, ccNameValue, paymentMethod.Actions.Save}
    Else
        ' existing credit card, only allow update of Active or expiration based on "description"
        Dim descriptionVal As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodDetails.Description, existingAcctNum)
        Dim activeVal As Value = CreateValue(paymentMethod.PaymentMethodSelection.Active, active.ToString())
        saveCommands = {customerVal, descriptionVal, ccExpName, ccExpValue, activeVal, paymentMethod.Actions.Save}
    End If
    Dim updateResult As AR303010Content() = m_context.AR303010Submit(saveCommands)

    Return ""
End Function
```

Another confusing part of this is that the two fields I would really like to let the user update are either the expiration date, or whether the card is Active.  But the Active flag is one of the fields in the list accessible from the Customer screen, and the expiration date is a field only accessible from the Payment Method screen.  If those are two different API calls, then will I need a different key field in each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This screen is difficult to use via web services for a few different reasons:

1. There is no unique key exposed via the screen that you can use to locate payment methods. The internal key is a field named PMInstanceID, and although you can technically refer to it via web service commands, it is not obvious to use
2. In Acumatica, payment method details are locked once one transaction using this payment method has been recorded. This means that to make modifications to it, you need to create a new payment method, and set the old one inactive.
3. There's a bug in the screen that only manifests when using it via web services, which is related to item above. When loading a payment method, system will disable the payment method details if there has been any transactions, but will fail to re-enable it if not. This is never a problem when using Acumatica from a web browser, since the fields are re-enabled automatically between every round-trip. But when automating this screen through web services, you're actually performing all the operations in a single round-trip. This problem has been reported and will be fixed shortly (internal JIRA reference is AC-54456)

That being said, there's a few things at our disposal that we can use to make this screen as easy to use from web services as other screens, and work around its limitations. By creating a customization project, we can add the PMInstanceID field (hereby referred to as the Token ID field) to the screen. You can store this token on your system, and use it for future operations with the payment method. Within the same customization project, we can also make the payment method details always enabled, allowing you to update expiration date on existing cards. Doing so also resolves the bug mentioned above where system won't allow you to add any new payment method to the system. The customization has two parts:

1. Overriding `CustomerPaymentMethod` DAC to make the PMInstanceID field accessible from the UI. This is done by appending the PXUIField attribute to the PMInstanceID field: `[PXUIField(DisplayName="Token ID", Visibility=PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]`. After that, the field may be added to the screen using the layout editor.
2. Handling the `CustomerPaymentMethod_RowSelected` event to force the payment methods details to always be enabled. We also use this event handler to hide the Token ID field when adding a new payment method, since this field would otherwise show `int.MinValue` until the payment method has been saved. The full code of the event looks like this:

   ```
   protected void CustomerPaymentMethod_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
   {
     if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
       InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

     // Force the payment method details to always be enabled to facilitate working via web services
     PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(Base.Details.Cache, null, true);

     // When adding a new method, field will have a temporary value corresponding to int.MinValue - don't show it
     PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<CustomerPaymentMethod.pMInstanceID>(cache, e.Row, cache.GetStatus(e.Row) != PXEntryStatus.Inserted);
   }
   ```

Once the customization is published, it becomes far easier to update existing payment methods. The code below shows how you can add a payment method, and retrieve the token ID that you will use later on to update the payment method:

```
    public int AddCreditCard(string customerID, string paymentMethod, string cardNumber, string expirationDate, string cvv, string nameOnCard)
    {
        if(_AR303010 == null) _AR303010 = _context.AR303010GetSchema();
        _context.AR303010Clear();

        var commands = new Command[]
        {
            new Value { Value = customerID, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer },
            new Value { Commit = true, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.Actions.Insert },
            new Value { Value = paymentMethod, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.PaymentMethod },
            new Value { Value = "CCDNUM", LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Description },
            new Value { Value = cardNumber, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, Commit = true },
            new Value { Value = "EXPDATE", LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Description },
            new Value { Value = expirationDate,  LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, Commit = true},
            new Value { Value = "CVV", LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Description },
            new Value { Value = cvv, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, Commit = true },
            new Value { Value = "NAMEONCC", LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Description },
            new Value { Value = nameOnCard,  LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, Commit = true },
            _AR303010.Actions.Save,
            _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.TokenID
        };

        var result = _context.AR303010Submit(commands.ToArray());
        return int.Parse(result[0].PaymentMethodSelection.TokenID.Value);
    }

    public void UpdateCreditCardExpirationDate(string customerID, string paymentMethod, int tokenID, string expirationDate)
    {
        if (_AR303010 == null) _AR303010 = _context.AR303010GetSchema();
        _context.AR303010Clear();

        var commands = new Command[]
        {
            new Value { Value = customerID, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer },
            new Value { Commit = true, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.Actions.Insert },
            new Value { Value = paymentMethod, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.PaymentMethod },
            new Value { Value = tokenID.ToString(), LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.TokenID },
            new Value { Value = "EXPDATE", LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Description },
            new Value { Value = expirationDate,  LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodDetails.Value, Commit = true},
            _AR303010.Actions.Save,
        };

        var result = _context.AR303010Submit(commands.ToArray());
    }

    public void MakeCardInactive(string customerID, string paymentMethod, int tokenID)
    {
        if (_AR303010 == null) _AR303010 = _context.AR303010GetSchema();
        _context.AR303010Clear();

        var commands = new Command[]
        {
            new Value { Value = customerID, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer },
            new Value { Commit = true, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.Actions.Insert },
            new Value { Value = paymentMethod, LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.PaymentMethod },
            new Value { Value = tokenID.ToString(), LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.TokenID },
            new Value { Value = "False", LinkedCommand = _AR303010.PaymentMethodSelection.Active },
            _AR303010.Actions.Save,
        };

        var result = _context.AR303010Submit(commands.ToArray());
    }
```

I wrapped these 3 functions into a class, and actual usage becomes quite simple:

```
    var paymentMethodManager = new PaymentMethodManager(context);
    int tokenID = paymentMethodManager.AddCreditCard("ABARTENDE", "MASTERCARD", "5111111111111118", "122016", "123", "John Doe");
    paymentMethodManager.UpdateCreditCardExpirationDate("ABARTENDE", "MASTERCARD", tokenID, "032017");
    paymentMethodManager.MakeCardInactive("ABARTENDE", "MASTERCARD", tokenID);
```

As of now, it is not possible to delete an existing payment method, and you must make it inactive instead. I've made the request for this enhancement, and it may come in the future.

*Note: I have placed all the code used in this answer on GitHub at https://github.com/gmichaud/acumatica-paymentmethod-ws-extensions.*